# Entity Framework - Define Formular Template

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I'm about to create an ASP.Net Web Application with MVC and EF for the following scenario:

Every month there are new people entering a department in our company. Until now we're using an Excel Spreadsheet to handle common "Workitems" such as granting filesystem permissions etc.

Now I want to handle those requests using a Webapplication but I'm stuck at creating the Model.

There are two different Requesttypes, "JoinRequest" and "ChangeRequest" for people joining the company and employees changing the department. For each request type there are different workitems defined. Those workitems should be displayed in the webapp when the corresponding request is selected. After the data is loaded the user has to enter the data for the workitems.

E.g.

[JoinRequest]
Add new Filesystem Access permission:
[ UNC Path ] [x] Read [ ] Read & Write

Here the user has to enter the UNC Path and the type of Accesslevel (R or RW).

For now I've got the following Model:

```
public abstract class DbItem {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DeletionDate { get; set; }
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public string DeletedBy { get; set; }

        public bool IsDeleted => DeletionDate != null;
    }

public abstract class Request : DbItem {
        public Department NewDepartment { get; set; }
        public DateTime BeginDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
        public ContractType ContractType { get; set; }
        public EmployeeType EmployeeType { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
        public string ContactUserId { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public User Contact {
            get {
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ContactUserId)) {
                    var userSearcher = new ActiveDirectoryUserSearcher();
                    return userSearcher.FindByUserID(ContactUserId);
                }
                return null;
            }
        }

        public string Phonenumber { get; set; }

        //public virtual List<RequestWorkItem> RequestWorkItems { get; set; }
        public bool IsFinished { get; set; }
        public abstract string GetRequestType();
    }

public abstract class WorkItem : DbItem {
        [Key]
        [ForeignKey("Language")]
        public int LanguageId { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public virtual Language Language { get; set; }

        public string WorkItemText { get; set; }
        public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    }

public class JoinRequest : Request {
        public Person Person { get; set; }

        public override string GetRequestType() {
            return "New";
        }
    }

public class FileSystemAccessWorkItem : AccessWorkItem {
        public FileSystemAccessRight FileSystemAccessRight { get; set; }
        public string FileSystemPath { get; set; }
    }
```

So when a user visits the website a new request has to be created but for every request type a set of workitems has to be loaded from the database. Additionally for every workitem the data the user entered should be saved somehow.

I hope you understand what I'm looking for - If anything is unclear I'll do my best to explain it more precisely

**Edit1:**
When looking at my Models I think the only think I achived is defining my Requests (so e.g. a JoinRequest contains some specific WorkItems) but how can I achive that a user is able to use this "RequestTemplate" to create a new Request and fill in the data to the corresponding workitems. Do I need additional Models for that? Maybe an example?

Comment: You didn't really ask a question.

Comment: I just fixed that, thank you!